# Import a module function from another folder in my module in python

Tags: python, import, module, python-module

I am currently constructing a custom module with an architecture like such:

```
module/
│
├── util/
│   ├── metrics.py
│   └── util.py
│
└── training/
    ├── pretraining.py
    └── training_step.py
```

In my `pretraining.py` script I need to use a function located in `util.py`. I am not sure how to import it in `pretraining.py`

So far I tried the classic:

```
from util.metrics import accuracy
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pretraining.py", line 5, in <module>
    from util.metrics import accuracy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'
```

How can I import the function in pretraining.py?

Comment: Look at my answer please

Comment: @arnino I just added some references on my answer, maybe it can contribute for a better understanding on how packages work in Python. Thanks for the accepting my answer as the more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As PCM indicated you have to create an empty `__init__.py` file inside each folder:

```
module/
├── __init__.py
│
├── util/
│   ├──__init__.py
│   ├── metrics.py
│   └── util.py
│
└── training/
    ├──__init__.py
    ├── pretraining.py
    └── training_step.py
```

So if in your pretraining.py script you need to use a function located in util/metrics.py:

```
from module.util.metrics import accuracy
```

Some references:

> https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp/blob/master/06-Modules%20and%20Packages/Useful_Info_Notebook.ipynb
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages
>
> https://python4astronomers.github.io/installation/packages.html

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you are trying to import from another folder. For that, you need to make it a package

You need to save an empty `__init__.py` file in the module folder, and subfolders.
`__init__.py` will make it a package, so you can import it using
`from util.metrics import accuracy`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I accepted @mseromenho answer as it is more clear